# Complexity of triple-nested Loop

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I have the following algorithm to find all triples

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
         for (int k = j+1; k < N; k++)
             if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0)
                { cnt++; }
```

I now that I have triple loop and I check all triples. How to show that the number of different triples that can be chosen from N items is precisely `N*(N-1)*(N-2)/6` ?

If we have two loops

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
             ...
```

when `i = 0` we go to the second loop `N-1` times

`i = 1` => `N-2` times

...

`i = N-1` => 1 time

`i = N` => 0 time

So `0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N-2 + N-1 = ((0 + N-1)/2)*N = N*N - N/2`

But how to do the same proof with triples?

Comment: Check out this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations

Comment: This might be more suited for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I'll do this step by step. It's more of a maths problem than anything.

Use a sample array for visualisation:

```
[1, 5, 7, 11, 6, 3, 2, 8, 5]
```

The first time the **3rd** nested loop begins at **7**, correct?

And the **2nd** at **5**, and the **1st** loop at **1**.

The **3rd** nested loop is the important one.

It will loop through `n-2` times. Then the **2nd** loop increments.

At this point the **3rd** loop loops through `n-3` times.

We keep adding these till we get.

```
[(n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 2 + 1 + 0]
```

Then the **1st** loop increments, so we begin at `n-3` this time.

So we get:

```
[(n-3) + ... + 2 + 1 + 0]
```

Adding them all together we get:

```
[(n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 2 + 1 + 0] +
[(n-3) + ... + 2 + 1 + 0]         +
[(n-4) + ... + 2 + 1 + 0]         +
.
.                                     <- (n-2 times)
.
[2 + 1 + 0]                       +
[1 + 0]                           +
[0]
```

We can rewrite this as:

```
(n-2)(1) + (n-3)(2) + (n-4)(3) + ... + (3)(n-4) + (2)(n-3) + (1)(n-2)
```

Which in maths notation we can write like this:

[image]

Make sure you look up the additive properties of Summations. (Back to college maths!)

We have

[image]

=

[image]              ...      *Remember how to convert sums to polynomials*

=

[image]

=

[image]

Which has a complexity of `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to realize that the number of such triples is equal to [C(n, 3)](http://www.mathwords.com/c/combination_formula.htm):

```
              n!
C(n, 3) =  --------
           3!(n-3)!

        = (n-2)(n-1)n/6
```

Another is to count what your loops do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
         for (int k = j+1; k < N; k++)
```

You've already showed that two loops from `0` to `n-1` execute `n(n-1)/2` operations.

For `i = 0`, the inner loops execute `(n-1)(n-2)/2` operations.

For `i = 1`, the inner loops execute `(n-2)(n-3)/2` operations.

...

For `i = N - 1`, the inner loops execute `0` operations.

We have:

```
(n-1)(n-2)/2 + (n-2)(n-3)/2 + ... =

= sum(i = 1 to n) {(n - i)(n - i - 1)/2}
= 1/2 sum(i = 1 to n) {n^2 - ni - n - ni + i^2 + i}
= 1/2 sum(i = 1 to n) {n^2} - sum{ni} - 1/2 sum{n} + 1/2 sum{i^2} + 1/2 sum{i}
= 1/2 n^3 - n^2(n+1)/2 - 1/2 n^2 + n(n+1)(2n+1)/12 + n(n+1)/4
```

Which reduces to the right formula, but it gets too ugly to continue here. You can check that it does on [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%20%20%20%3D%201%2F2%20n%5E3%20-%20n%5E2%28n%2B1%29%2F2%20-%201%2F2%20n%5E2%20%2B%20%28n%28n%2B1%29%282n%2B1%29%29%2F12%20%2B%20n%28n%2B1%29%2F4).