# Computing worst case time complexity with algorithms

Tags: algorithm, math, time, case

this is a question on my study guide, but I'm unsure how to begin the problem, or even what the code "to n do" means. I've seen some other questions be answered that are also looking for worst case time complexity, but nothing with code similar to this problem. I'm just looking for a general way to solve these problems, so if there's a go to method, I would really like some help. The question is below.

```
Compute the worst case time complexity of the following algorithm.

for i = 1 to n do
    for j = 1 to i do
        for k = 1 to j do
            print(i,j,k).
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there is no best or worst case time complexity in this case, just **the** time complexity. As mentioned in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worst-case_complexity) wikipedia article, the best and worst cases are generally applicable to functions such as sorting functions, where the time taken by the algorithm would be dependent upon how the input was initial sorted. Thus in your case, following the results of the matlab code below, I would say that the time complexity is

```
1/6*n*(n+1)*(n+2)
```

This was arrived at by running the code for different values of n, and noting that each increment to n adds the corresponding triangle number of print statements, i.e.

```
sum_{i = 1}^{n} 1/2*i*(i+1) = 1/6*n*(n+1)*(n+2)
```

Matlab code:

```
n = 5;

count = 0;
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:i
        for k = 1:j
            count = count + 1;
        end
    end
end

1/6*n*(n+1)*(n+2)
count
```

Comment: While very practical, I think the question (and questioner) is looking for a bit more of an analytical approach

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered some times already, you can check them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18486543/what-is-the-complexity-of-this-nested-triple-for-loop) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937447/complexity-of-triple-nested-loop) for the mathematical explanation.

Basically, since it is a triple nested loop, the worst time would be **0(n³)**

Comment: While true, the loop indices are kind of interesting, perhaps worth mentioning?

Comment: Thanks, I just had trouble finding other questions that used pseudo code instead of actual code. It's just easier for me to understand that way.

Comment: @LamarLatrell Since it is the worst case, I believe it is safe to assume the value of the indices are sort of irrelevant and can be seen simply as **n**. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You're correct in the complexity/big-Oh case. I now see the links, apologies, I didn't see them on the mobile interface I was just using...  They sit in place of what I was suggesting.